# magento - how to show only configurable product in main category, simple product in sub-category

Tags: magento-1.8, category, configurable-product

I want to know how can I do this. I want to when i click main category, just show configurable product in page, and when i click sub-category, show simple product in page. Please help me in this, it will be really appreciated.
i'm newbie
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your simple products are "Catalog, Search", you can simply only assign the configurable products to the top category, and only the simple products to the sub category. Also, make sure the top category is not set as an anchor category.